# Meaning of an excerpt from Seneca

Tags: meaning

I am having trouble understanding the sense of the sentences in bold type (below) from Seneca's essay "[Of Benefits](https://books.google.com/books?id=VGWp6XGTriIC&pg=PA50&dq=%22no+good+offices+after+a+disappointment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A1udVYvGDI__yQTx0JHIBg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22no%20good%20offices%20after%20a%20disappointment%22&f=false)":

> It is a common saying, "I gave such or such a man so much money; I would I had thrown it into the sea;" and yet the merchant trades again after piracy, and the banker ventures afresh after a bad security. **He that will do no good offices after a disappointment must stand still, and do just nothing at all. The plough goes on after a barren year; and while the ashes are yet warm, we raise a new house upon the ruins of a former.**

Comment: I see no use of ***this*** anywhere in your passage, what could you be talking about?

Comment: This is pretty clear. Are you confused by the archaic use of *offices*? Even so, don't the five separate analogies help you understand the fundamental message? In case it is *offices* that's tripping you up, I suggest when you find yourself in this situation that you look up the word in a good dictionary, and see if there are any additional definitions, which you may not already be familiar with, that do make sense in context. For "*offices*", check out the OED's sense 5: "*A service or kindness done, or attention shown or given, towards anyone. Chiefly with qualification, as good office*".

Comment: Hello, Laurie Sorber Rockenbach, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I found the origin of the quotation that puzzles you and added a sentence before it to provide some context for it—but be aware that this question is headed for closing unless you can be more specific about what in particular you find hard to understand in Seneca's (or Seneca's translator's) wording. Note that the translation is from 1855, so part of the problem may simply be unusual word choice (such as "offices") or diction (such as "a former [house]"), by today's standards.

Comment: I think it means even after failure, disaster, or disappointment we must try again or continue in our efforts. Although I may be interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is a question on Latin literature.

Comment: well, a **translation** of Latin.

Answer (score 1):

**The plough goes on after a barren year** - a metaphor meaning we must continue with our lives even after life has been difficult for us for an extended period of time.

**while the ashes are yet warm, we raise a new house upon the ruins of a former** - a metaphor meaning that, even after suffering a disaster we must build a new life.

**He that will do no good offices after a disappointment must stand still, and do just nothing at all.** - an exhortation to continue contributing to society even after suffering a personal disappointment.

Nowadays we use phrases such as:

"Oh well, life goes on."

"The show must go on."

"Pick yourself up, dust yourself off and start all over again."

"When the going gets tough, the tough get going.

"When life gives you lemons, make lemonade."

"Just because Fate doesn't deal you the right cards, it doesn't mean you should give up."

etc.

Comment: Kind of ironic that the dude killed himself after he lost influence in court with Nero.

Comment: @Oldcat - Mind you, he didn't have much choice. It was an order from the emperor and the alternative would have been a lot less pleasant!